# Unable to change the color of a "MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a "MetroFramework.Controls.MetroButton" with a dark grey color and a light grey color on mouse over.

I want to change these 2 colors but I can't do that despite the color change in the property panel.

I even tried to change the colors in FlatAppearence (circled in pink) but it does nothing

Do you know why?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this Winforms?

Comment: How to check if it is Winforms or not?

Comment: @zollen123 is there any xaml ? then its not Winforms, but I can tell its winforms from your properties, try reloading the form after changing the properties

Comment: In my project I have no xaml file. I had already tried to reload the form but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Do you know what the Metrobutton is really for?
 According to you, is it possible to replace these "Metrobuttons" by normal buttons?